# RerwiteRule doesn't work on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Why it doesn't work when I request `http://localhost/webme/test`

I work on localhost
Physical root folder is c:\AppServ\www\WebME
The script is saved in .htaccess in the root folder

It should be redirect to http://localhost/webme/index.php?page=test

Comment: you want webme/test to go to index.php?page=webme or index.php?page=test?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite is changing `/webme/test` to `/index.php?page=test`. The question is if your .htaccess file is in "/webme/" or in the document root ("/").

If your document root is in `c:\AppServ\www\` and your .htaccess file is in the `webme` directory, you need to include "webme" in the target:

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /webme/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

OR by removing the leading slash in your target

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Otherwise, if your .htaccess is in the document root ("/") then you need to match against it:

```
RewriteRule ^webme/([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /webme/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```